# Same size on gallery cards in TailwindCSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, image-gallery

I have an image gallery in Tailwind CSS with React. It looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

Each image component is defined life this:

```
<div className="flex items-center">
      <div className="rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg">
        <img
          className="w-full h-48 object-cover"
          src={img}
          loading="lazy"
          alt={""}
        />

        <div className="p-6">
          <div className="flex items-baseline">
            <div className="">{name}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and it's loaded on this container:

```
<div className="grid gap-6 mb-8 md:grid-cols-2 xl:grid-cols-4">
{images.map(img => <ImageComponent ..../>)}
</div>
```

As you can see the descriptions make the cards longer than others. **How can I have the cards in the same row the same size without cutting the word?**

I'm using `"tailwindcss": "1.4.6"`

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 3):

I've solved this before by putting the card contents in a `flex-column` and stretching the content area to fill the flex by giving it `flex-1`. For example:

```
<div className="rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg">
  <div className="flex flex-column">
    <img
      className="w-full h-48 object-cover"
      src={img}
      loading="lazy"
      alt={""}
    />

    <div className="flex-1 p-6">
      <div className="">{name}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```